# I am trying to login with my Apps. I dont understand the mistake. I prove my code for a example more easy and this had work it. thanks

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0

when i click login button after enter email and password i got the error as "unfortunately,myapp has beeen stopped" and i got error message as FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 and An error occurred while executing doInBackground().
for ref i have attached code. thanks for help

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button submitBtn,registerBtn,forgotpassBtn;
    EditText emailEt,passwordEt;
    //SessionManager session;

    //Driver Login Fields
    EditText drloginEmail;
    EditText drloginPassword;
    TextView drloginResult;
    Button loginSubmitBtn;

    //Registration Fields
    EditText registrationName,registrationEmail,registrationPhone,registrationPassword,registrationConfirmPassword;
    TextView registrationResult;

    //LostPass Fields
    EditText lostPassEmail;
    TextView lostPassResltText;

    SharedPreferences sh;

    JSONParser jparser=new JSONParser();

    private static final String regiURL = "http://10.0.2.2/appslider/registration.php";
    public static final String loginURL = "http://10.0.2.2/appslider/login.php";
    public static final String getDataURL = null;
    public static final String recoverPasswordURL = "http://10.0.2.2/sendmail.php";

    Context con;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);

        con=LoginActivity.this;

        sh=getSharedPreferences("CRUZER_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);

        init();

        String email=sh.getString("loginemail", null);
        String pass=sh.getString("loginpass", null);
        boolean driver=sh.getBoolean("type", false);

        if(email!=null && pass!=null && !driver){
            emailEt.setText(email);
            passwordEt.setText(pass);
            submitBtn.performClick();
        }else if(email!=null && pass!=null && driver){
            showDriverLoginDialog();
            drloginEmail.setText(email);
            drloginPassword.setText(pass);
            loginSubmitBtn.performClick();
        }

    }

    private void init() {

        submitBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.loginSubmitBtn);
        registerBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.loginRegisterBtn);
        forgotpassBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.loginForgotPassBtn);

        submitBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        registerBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        forgotpassBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        emailEt=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmailEt);
        passwordEt=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassEt);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(!Util.isConnectingToInternet(this)){
            Util.showNoInternetDialog(this);
            return;
        }

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.loginSubmitBtn:
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(emailEt.getText().toString())){
                    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(passwordEt.getText().toString())){
                        new Login().execute("client");
                    }else Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your email address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.loginRegisterBtn:
                showRegisterDialog();
                break;
            case R.id.loginForgotPassBtn:
                showLostPasswordDialog();
                break;
        }
    }

    class Login extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
        ProgressDialog pDialog;
        String s="";
        int success=-1;
        int error=0;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog=new ProgressDialog(con);
            pDialog.setMessage("Login is processing......");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        boolean driver=false;
        String email="";
        String password="";
        String drloginEmail;
        String drloginPassword;
        String emailEt;
        String passwordEt;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... st) {

            if(st!=null && st[0].equals("driver")){
                //email=drloginEmail.getText().toString();
                email=this.drloginEmail.toString();
                //password=drloginPassword.getText().toString();
                password=this.drloginPassword.toString();
                driver=true;
            }else{
                //email=emailEt.getText().toString();
                email=this.emailEt.toString();
                //password=passwordEt.getText().toString();
                password=this.passwordEt.toString();
            }

            List<NameValuePair> params=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

            if(driver)params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category", "driver"));
            else params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category", "client"));

            UserInfo.setEmail(email);
            UserInfo.setPassword(password);

            try {
                JSONObject jobj=jparser.makeHttpRequest(loginURL, "POST", params);
                success=jobj.getInt("success");
                s=jobj.getString("message");

                if(success==1){
                    JSONObject job=jobj.getJSONArray("info").getJSONObject(0);
                    UserInfo.setName(job.getString("name"));
                    UserInfo.setPhonenumber(job.getString("number"));
                    UserInfo.setId(job.getString("id"));
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                //  e.printStackTrace();
                error=1;
            }catch(Exception e){
                error=1;
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();

            if(error==1){
                if(Util.isConnectingToInternet(con)){
                    Toast.makeText(con, "Server is down, Please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else
                    Util.showNoInternetDialog(con);
                return;
            }

            if(success==0){
                Toast.makeText(con, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else if(success==1){
                /*GetUserData data=new GetUserData();
                data.execute();*/

                SharedPreferences.Editor edit=sh.edit();
                edit.putString("loginemail", email);
                edit.putString("loginpass", password);
                edit.putBoolean("type", driver);
                edit.commit();


                Intent i=new Intent(con, DriverPositionActivity.class);
                if(driver)
                    i=new Intent(con, DriverActivity.class);

                startActivity(i);
                Toast.makeText(con, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi ,thanks for ur info. but i couldnot solve this issue sir

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have done inside doInBackground

```
        if(st!=null && st[0].equals("driver")){
            //email=drloginEmail.getText().toString();
            email=this.drloginEmail.toString();
            //password=drloginPassword.getText().toString();
            password=this.drloginPassword.toString();
            driver=true;
        }else{
            //email=emailEt.getText().toString();
            email=this.emailEt.toString();
            //password=passwordEt.getText().toString();
            password=this.passwordEt.toString();
        }
```

here inside login async class you have not initilize variables named as drloginEmail,passwordEt and you are fetching data from that may be this is a issue. Please initilize these variables with the values getting from corresponding  EditText's.

Comment: hi ,thanks for ur info. but i couldnot solve this issue sir